# react modal does not open with useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which renders a `react-modal`, my problem is the `react-modal` does not open. `modalFileNameOpen` `useState` property does not set properly.

```
const [modalFileNameOpen, setmodalFileNameOpen] = useState(false)

const handleFileNameChangeClick = () => {
    console.log(modalFileNameOpen)    // set to false
    setmodalFileNameOpen(true)     // this does not set the `modalFileNameOpen` to true. 
    console.log(modalFileNameOpen)    // is still false
}

return (
<div className="container-fluid">
    <input type="button" className="btn" onClick={handleFileNameChangeClick} value="Rename File"></input>

    <ModalFileName modalFileNameOpen={modalFileNameOpen} />

  </div>
)
```

I have another component `ModalFileName`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
Modal.setAppElement('#root');
const ModalFileName = ({ modalFileNameOpen }) => {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(modalFileNameOpen)

    return (
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}>
            <div>
                <h1>File Name Change</h1>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}>Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default ModalFileName;
```

Comment: You will not see the new state until the next render. Also I don't see a `useEffect` call?

Comment: @pilchard new to react, can yu please explai, my understanding was prop change re-renders the component.

Comment: @pilchard modified OP.................

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example of what you seem to be trying to achieve.

It is a basic illustration of pulling state up to the parent and passing a handler function down to the child. In your code you were attempting to do this by declaring a new state in the child based on the parent's state which leads to unnecessary duplication and possible state conflicts down the road.

We declare our modal state and setter and a basic handler function:

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(!openModal);
  }
```

We then conditionally render our modal component based on the current state value. If `openModal` is false we render the button to open it, otherwise we render the Modal component and pass our handler function `toggleModal` to it as a prop.

```
// if openModal is false render the button, else render our modal
{!openModal ?
   <button type="button" onClick={toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
   : <Modal handler={toggleModal} />
}
```

If the modal is rendered it recieves the handler (here retrieved through destructuring `function Modal({handler}) {...`) and assign it to the `onClick` of the close button on our modal.

```
function Modal({handler}) {

  return (
    <div className="modal" >
      <p>I'm a modal</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handler}>Close Modal</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

**Working Example**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: gray;
}

.modal {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: aqua;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="App"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(!openModal);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {!openModal ?
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
      : <Modal handler={toggleModal} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

function Modal({handler}) {

  return (
    <div className="modal" >
      <p>I'm a modal</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handler}>Close Modal</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));
 </script>
```

---

**Some notes**

If you `console.log()` before and after the `setOpenModal()` call you will get the same results that you did in your question; it will print the same value that it entered the render with. If it doesn't there is a problem and you have mutated the state. From the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    console.log(openModal);   // prints the value of openModal on entering render
    setOpenModal(!openModal); // sets openModal to !openModal
    console.log(openModal);   // prints the value of openModal on entering render 
  }
```

Also, you may want to pass arguments to your passed handler (arguably the `close` button should always set `openModal` to `false` rather than hoping that toggling it will close it).

To do this you can simply accept an argument in your handler function.

```
const toggleModal = (newState) => {
    setOpenModal(newState);
  }
```

and pass it in your `onClick` calls.

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => toggleModal(true)}>Open Modal</button>
```

```
function Modal({handler}) {

  return (
    <div className="modal" >
      <p>I'm a modal</p>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handler(false)}>Close Modal</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```